# Need help debugging Verilog I2C slave code

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, i2c, simulation, testbench

[image]

As you can see in the waveforms and the code after the start (busy line goes high) condition occurs, I start sending the slave address bit by bit in the testbench through the `SDA` line, and this needs to get stored in the `address` register. And in the Addr Ackn state, it checks whether the `address` matches, and depending on the last bit of the address, it goes into read or write state as written in the code.

But, here for reasons unknown, the `address` register isn't able to capture the address from the `SDA` line accurately and hence the FSM is going to a `HOLD` state.

Can anyone provide suggestions on the issue?

And this is the relevant code snippet.

```
module I2C_SLAVE #(parameter SLAVE_ADDR = 7'b1101010)    // Slave Address for this module is 0x6A
    (
     input Reset_L,    // (WIRE) Active Low Reset to clear the data within slave and reset the registers
     input SCL,        // (WIRE) Serial Clock 
     inout SDA         // (WIRE) Serial Data
    );

// STATES OF STATE MACHINE BETWEEN START AND STOP CONDITION
localparam ADDRESS   = 3'b000;     // Address from the master is read and checked with slave address
localparam ADDR_ACKN = 3'b001;     // Acknowledgement from slave to master is sent from if address matches
localparam RECEIVE   = 3'b010;     // If Address last bit is 0 then data is received from master to slave (WRITE OPERATION)
localparam RX_ACKN   = 3'b011;     // Sends an Acknowledgement to master after the data is received
localparam TRANSMIT  = 3'b100;     // If Address last bit is 1 then data is transmitted from slave to master (READ OPERATION)
localparam TX_ACKN   = 3'b101;     // Waits for Acknowledgement from master after the data is transmitted
localparam HOLD      = 3'b110;     // It is the rest state which implies slave is not active

// STATE MACHINE VARIABLE
reg [2:0] state_machine;

// REGISTERS FOR INTERNAL OPERATIONS
reg       busy;                    // Used to activate and deactivate FSM (SLAVE)

reg [7:0] address;                 // Used to hold the input serial data
reg [2:0] bit_index;               // Used in accessing each bit of address and data register

reg [7:0] slave_data;              // Data held by the slave

// CONTROL REGISTERS TO ACTIVATE OUTPUT FUNCTION OF SDA
reg       SDA_EN;                  // Controls when the SDA should act as output
reg       SDA_OUT;                 // Holds the serial data to be transmitted from slave

// SDA INPUT AND OUTPUT TRANSITION
assign SDA = (SDA_EN) ? SDA_OUT : 'bz;    // [SDA_EN == 1] => O/P pin and [SDA_EN == 0] => I/P pin

// START CONDITION
always @(negedge SDA)              // If SDA goes low when SCL is high then start condition occurs
begin
    if (SCL == 1)                  // If busy is already high then repeated start condition occurs
    begin
        address       <= 8'b0;     // Address reg is reset to store the new address transmitted from master
        bit_index     <= 3'b111;   // Bit Index reg is preset as the first data transmitted will be MSB
        state_machine <= ADDRESS;  // SM variable is set to first state where address is obtained
        if (busy == 0)
            busy <= 1'b1;          // Busy reg is made high indicating the slave FSM is active
    end
end

// FSM for state operations

always @(posedge SCL)              
    begin
        if (~Reset_L)                  
        begin
            SDA_EN     <= 1'b0;
            SDA_OUT    <= 1'b0;
            slave_data <= 8'b0;
        end
    
    if (busy == 1)
    begin
        case(state_machine)
            ADDRESS:
            begin
                if (bit_index > 0)
                begin
                    address[bit_index] <= SDA;
                    bit_index <= bit_index - 1;  // Bit index reg is decremented until last bit is received 
                 end
                 else
                   state_machine <= ADDR_ACKN;               
            end
            
            

ADDR_ACKN:
                begin
                    if (address[7:1] == SLAVE_ADDR)          // Compares the address transmitted by master with the slave's address
                    begin
//                      SDA_OUT <= 1'b1;                     // If address matched, based on operation to be performed the FSM moves to next state
                        bit_index <= 3'b111;                 // Presets the bit index reg
                        if(address[0] == 0)                  // If Address Bit[0] == 0 then slave becomes data receiver
                            state_machine <= RECEIVE;        // WRITE OPERATION
                        else                                 // If Address Bit[0] == 1 then slave becomes data transmitter
                            state_machine <= TRANSMIT;       // READ OPERATION
                    end
                    else
                        state_machine <= HOLD;               // If address does not match slave moves to HOLD state
                end
```

Comment: We have no idea what hardware  -or software- OP is talking about. 
And I somehow missed the verilog tag. Whoops.
Note that in classic I²C both I/Os should be used in open drain mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the slave address to `7'b1101010` (`7'h6a`) in the design, but your design received `8'b01010100` in `address[7:0]` according to your waveforms.  This means `address[7:1]` is `7'b0101010`, which is `7'h2a`.  The received address`7'h2a` does not match the expected address `7'h6a` in the design.  This is why the state machine goes to the `HOLD` state unexpectedly.

The problem is that you have a simulation race condition because `SDA` and `SCL` change at the same time.  You should change the testbench so that they are changing at different times.  Refer to an [I2C timing diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C#Timing_diagram).  Here is one way to code the testbench to demonstrate the signals changing at different times:

```
module tb;
reg sda_tb, scl_tb;
parameter PERIOD = 20;

initial begin
    sda_tb = 1;
    #(PERIOD/4) sda_tb = 0;
    set_address(7'h6a);
    #(PERIOD) $finish;
end

initial begin
    scl_tb = 1;
    forever #(PERIOD/2) scl_tb = ~scl_tb;
end

task set_address (input [6:0] addr);
    integer i;
    for (i=6; i>=0; i=i-1) begin
        #(PERIOD) sda_tb <= addr[i];
    end
endtask
endmodule
```

[image: waves]